# Does marking an event handler as "passive" delay its invocation or reduce the number of invocations?

Tags: javascript, events, browser, event-handling, dom-events

I'll come straight out with it: does marking a JS event handler as `passive` affect when the browser's JS runtime invokes it? Does affect how often it gets called?

I ask because I'm working on JS that monitors site performance. Hence we have to strike a delicate balance between being accurate and negatively affecting the performance of the very site we're monitoring.

I've done some informal tests but they proved inconclusive.

EDIT: I've done further, better tests and found that the `passive` handler was called as frequently and as "quickly" as the non-passive event handler. FTR when scrolling, both were always called in under 4ms (elapsed time since `event.timeStamp`).

Comment: check this out: [Improving Scroll Performance with Passive Event Listeners](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners). For all I can find. Although, the description of this flag is quite general, it seems to only affect scrolling in combination with touch-events

Comment: thanks @Thomas. I don't think that link answers the questions though, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'll come straight out with it: does marking a JS event handler as passive affect when the browser's JS runtime invokes it? Does affect how often it gets called?
Yes

Does marking an event handler as “passive” delay its invocation or reduce the number of invocations?

No, it will note reduce invocation

Comment: See my EDIT: section - that's not what I observed from a few hours of testing on different sites pages and pages. Curious.